# Xtext - Couldn't resolve reference to JvmOperation

Tags: xtext

I am trying to create a small DSL language using XText.

`grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl with  org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.Xbase
import "http://www.eclipse.org/xtext/common/JavaVMTypes" as jvmTypes
generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"`

```
StartState:
'startState'
     'evaluate' ref=JvmTypeReference "-" op=[jvmTypes::JvmOperation]
'end';
```

Following is the ScopeProvider Implementation:

```
public class MyScopeProvider extends AbstractDeclarativeScopeProvider {

IScope scope_StartState_op(StartState call, EReference reference) {
    JvmType type = call.getRef().getType();
    List<IEObjectDescription> descriptions = new ArrayList<IEObjectDescription>();

    if (type instanceof JvmGenericType) {
        JvmGenericType gt = (JvmGenericType) type;
        for (JvmMember member : gt.getMembers()) {
            if (member instanceof JvmOperation) {
                descriptions.add(EObjectDescription.create(member.getSimpleName(), member));
            }
        }
    }
    return new SimpleScope(descriptions);
}}
```

I type following into the resulting editor

```
startState evaluate controller.Controller - perform end
```

Here I am able to get the code completion working for method (perform which is in controller.Controller class) as expected. But I am in need of help to resolve the following error which happens after the code completion.

> Couldn't resolve reference to JvmOperation 'perform'.

Also, I tried following [Peter's Blog](http://www.peterfriese.de/writing-xtext-scope-providers-with-xtend/) with no success

Comment: which xtext version do you use? how does the declaration line of the grammar look like? it works fine for me using 2.8.2 and inhering org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.Xtype

Comment: @ChristianDietrich - I added the grammar at the top of the question. Please have a look. Also I am using Xtext 2.8.2 on Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)  Build id: 20150219-0600

Comment: @ChristianDietrich - Thank you very much for the tip. I was using   `org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.Xbase`  instead of `org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.Xtype`

Answer (score 0):

Posting answer to my own question. The grammer should look like the following.

`grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl with  org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.Xtype
import "http://www.eclipse.org/xtext/common/JavaVMTypes" as jvmTypes
generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"`

`StartState:
'startState'
     'evaluate' ref=JvmTypeReference "-" op=[jvmTypes::JvmOperation]
'end';`

There is no change to the scope provider and the usage.